# Можно ли кивнуть и моргнуть с намеком?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Он кивнул и моргнул ей с намеком, что опасаться нечего.

Он, кивнув, моргнул ей с тем намеком, что опасаться нечего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Он, кивнув, моргнул ей с тем намеком, что опасаться нечего.***

Грамматических и семантических ошибок здесь нет. Для проверки стилистической корректности нужен контекст.